# Windows program to make multiple images visible in a window as reference

Tags: windows, images, image-viewer, image, reference-management

I need a program I can just keep running with a bunch of images in the same window like images to view as reference. i have just been importing a bunch of images into a photoshop document and putting them next to each other but that takes a lot of time and space. i have looked at MultimgViewer but that just displays single images. i guess to put it more simply im looking for a way to make a mood board (not using google slides)

i am on windows 10. i would be willing to spend up to $20.

Comment: So, are you asking for a program that loads a bunch of images and automatically tile them up? What if images are of a very different size? For example, one has 150x100 pixels and the other has 1500x1200. What would the program have to do, resize them, so they fit in a similar rectangular shape, or keep the original size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PureRef allows you to drop images with the mouse.

Available for Windows/Linux/OSX.
Free, not open source.

[image]

https://www.pureref.com/

Answer (score 1):

Krita has a [Reference Image tool](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/tools/reference_images_tool.html) which allows loading up several images in a canvas and use it as a sort of a mood board.

It can add images from files, or system clipboard, embed them or link them from external files, and freely place them in or around the canvas with rotation scaling or color adjustments.

In [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RIOLf31lpw) you can see it in action.

This isn't much different from building it in photoshop, other that it keeps live links to files, rather than make a huge image.

Answer (score 0):

Flickr albums do this, not that I would recommend Flickr for general use these days. Just take all the relevant photos, upload them into Flickr, and categorize them into the same album.

There are probably a lot of alternative photo sites (e.g. Google Photos?) that do the same, just as a matter of course.